# Why does assigning a deep property on an instance modify the prototype property instead of throwing an error?

Tags: javascript

Considering that assigning a property on an instance creates a local instance property, even when the same property already exists on the prototype.

Why does assigning a deep property on an instance modify the prototype property instead of throwing an error?

I'm assuming what happens here is when you try to assign `joe.attributes.head.eyes`, it first tries to find `attributes` as a local property on `joe`. Since it doesn't find it there, it follows the scope chain and does find `attributes` on the `Person` prototype. Then it continues to find the full property chain on the `Person` prototype (`attributes.head.eyes`). Therefore it modifies the prototype property.

However, I feel like this should throw an error (because `attributes` is undefined on `joe`, therefore can't have properties assigned to it) since you're not explicitly modifying the prototype (e.g. `joe.constructor.prototype.attributes.head.eyes = 1`). It seems like this could lead to a great deal of confusion because you aren't really sure when you're modifying instance properties or prototype properties.

Supporting code ([or this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bryandowning/z4m37/)):

```
var Person = (function() {

    function Person( name ) {
        this.name = name;
        Person.prototype.population++;
    }

    Person.prototype.population = 0;

    Person.prototype.attributes = {
        head: {
            eyes: 2,
            nose: 1,
            mouth: 1,
            ears: 2
        }
    };

    return Person;

})();

joe = new Person('Joe');
sue = new Person('Sue');


joe.population = 10;

console.log( 'Set joe.population equal to 10. Creates a population instance property. Does NOT modify prototype.' );
console.log( 'joe.population', joe.population ); // 10
console.log( 'sue.population', sue.population ); // 2


joe.attributes.head.eyes = 1;

console.log( 'Changed joe.attributes.head.eyes from 2 to 1. Does NOT create a attributes.head.eyes instance property. DOES modify prototype.' );
console.log( 'joe.attributes.head.eyes', joe.attributes.head.eyes ); // 1
console.log( 'sue.attributes.head.eyes', sue.attributes.head.eyes ); // 1
```

Comment: By that logic, _read_ access to a property that is not available on the instance, but part of the prototype should throw an error as well … and that would make no sense at all, because it would make prototyping rather senseless.

Comment: Ok, so why does assigning `population` NOT modify the prototype? The behavior seems inconsistent.

Comment: I think that has to do with `Person.prototype.attributes` being an object – and objects are passed by reference in JavaScript, as opposed to primitive values; so all your `Person` instances “share” that object between them.

Comment: it isn't inconsistent. assignment creates a new property where one does not exist.

Comment: I had the same thought @CBroe, but it breaks down for me because there isn't actually a reference to `attributes` on the instance. It doesn't exist on the instance. It exists on `Person`'s prototype. Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: @Woody - unless it can't. For example, `var a = {}; a.b.c = true;` throws an error (as it should because it has no idea what `b` is).

Comment: Yes, it exists on the prototype – but is is the _same one_ for all Person objects, _because_ it’s a referenced object. Have a look at this [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4m37/3/), where I moved `attributes` into the constructor – that way, each time a _new_ object is created when you create a new Person, and as result in console you see that only joe becomes a pirate …

Comment: @CBroe But it seems like reference has nothing to do with it. If you have a number stored on the prototype, it's still shared among all instances (like `population`) - not by reference, but by the nature of prototype. P.S. something ate your fiddle. I see no pirates.

Comment: a.b.c fails to resolve because neither a nor the prototype of a nor any objects in the prototype chain have a property called b. this is not the case with Joe and his attributes

Comment: We are using the term “sharing” differently here. Yes, the prototype properties are “shared” amongst all objects, in the meaning that each gets its own inherited. But your `attributes` is an object reference – so although each of your Persons has their own `attribute` property, they _reference_ the same object. (And whatcha mean my fiddle was eaten, can’t you access http://jsfiddle.net/z4m37/3/ …?)

Comment: But each instance does _not_ have its own `attributes` property. (lmao, he's a pirate because he lost an eye - well played. I was looking for a new `pirate` property.)

Comment: Isn't the prototype the referenced object that is stored on each instance?

Answer (score 0):

consider the alternative. are you suggesting that the interpreter spots that attributes is on the prototype and dynamically gives Joe his own attributes, head and eyes all with an = statement ? surely that would be even more confusing.

what you see might seem odd, but it makes sense given that the prototype chain has already been traversed to reach attributes in the first place.

Comment: what you are in effect saying with the arrangement you have is that all Persons share an attributes object, if you change that object (which has it's own prototype chain) then all persons will see that change. if you didn't want this to be the case then clearly you need to make sure that all Persons have their own attributes object.

Comment: the mistake you are making is implied by your comment that changing Joe.attributes.head.eyes "changes the prototype" it doesn't. it changes an object referenced by the prototype which is quite different.

Comment: Is that object not stored on the prototype?

Comment: No. a reference to it is stored on the prototype.